# Bayesian belief network - calculate probability

Tags: probability, bayesian-network

> Given the following Bayesian belief network, what is the probability
> that a non-smoking patient with a smoking parent will develop lung
> tumor?

[image]

In this question, isn't the answer already provided within the question itself? As I understand it, I required to calculate the probability of developing a lung tumor given that the patient does not smoke, but their parent does. However, this information is already provided in the table at the bottom right. Am I missing something?

Comment: It looks to me that you are correct.

Comment: @nicola thanks! weird so this is very stupid question.

Comment: It is just an exercise in reading the table.  That is fairly basic, but that is where you start.